# Clipping with Web Audio: How to make Firefox behave like Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Code snippet executed in [Canopy](https://hoch.github.io/canopy/):

```
// @channels 1
// @duration 0.25
// @sampleRate 44100

var osc = new OscillatorNode(context);
var gain = context.createGain();
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(2, 0.25/2);
osc.connect(gain);
gain.connect(context.destination);
osc.start();
```

Recording with [Audacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)):

[image: Annotated screenshot of Audacity recording showing clipping in Chrome]

Chrome 74 clips, Firefox 66 doesn't.

*Can I get Firefox to clip the signal too?* (which is what I'd expect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure the output is clipped, you can do it in at least three ways:

- Use a `WaveShaperNode` to perform the clipping for you. (Available everywhere).
- Use a `ScriptProcessorNode` (deprecated) to do the clipping.
- Use an `AudioWorkletNode` to do the clipping. (Not yet available everywhere.)

Example: (added by OP, please double check)

```
// @channels 1
// @duration 0.25
// @sampleRate 44100

var osc = new OscillatorNode(context);
var gain = context.createGain();
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(2, 0.25/2);
osc.connect(gain);

var waveShaper = new WaveShaperNode(context, {
    curve: new Float32Array([-1, 1])
});
gain.connect(waveShaper);
waveShaper.connect(context.destination);

osc.start();
```

Comment: what is going on exactly then? what does firefox do to prevent clipping, and why (makes no sense to me)

Comment: File a bug with Firefox?  I asked a FireFox WebAudio guy and he said he doesn't recall Firefox doing any kind of compression and was expecting the behavior to be like Chrome.